# Get caret position on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, redactor

I'm having a hard time doing something that should be simple: getting the caret position where a user clicks in a Paragraph.  This is complicated because I'm creating and destroying instances of the WYSIWYG text editor [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) contextually based on user input, which modifies the DOM.

My structure:

```
<div class='node'>
    <div class='hierarchy'></div>
    <div class='content'>
        <h2>Test Heading</h2>
        <p>Content that user might click on.  Need to find position where I should insert cursor after initialising Redactor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the text, I'm initialising an instance of redactor, which modifies the DOM like so:

```
<div class='node'>
    <div class="hierarchy"></div>
    <div class="redactor_box">
        <div id="redactorToolbar">... ul etc ...</div>
        <div class="content redactor_editor" contenteditable="true">
            <h2>Test Heading</h2>
            <p>Content that user might click on.  Need to find position where I should insert cursor after initialising Redactor</p>
        </div>
        <textarea dir="ltr" style="height: 90px; display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the redactor has been initialised, I want to position the cursor where the user originally clicked.  Pretty straightforward, right?  Well, in my click handler (which is attached to the div.node), `window.getSelection()` returns the position of the caret PRIOR TO the click:

```
Node.prototype.onClick = function (e, ui) {
    var $el = $(this),
        node = $el.data('node'),
        document = node.document,
        selection = window.getSelection();

    console.log('rangeCount: ', selection.rangeCount);
    console.log('type: ', selection.type);
    console.log('anchorOffset: ', selection.anchorOffset);

    if ($el.has('.redactor_box').length <= 0) {
        document.setRedactor(node);
    }
};
```

Say for example I:

1. Click on `<p>` at char 5

   - Prints "rangeCount: 0, type: None, anchorOffset: 0"
   - Initialises Redactor, wrapping the content `DIV` and making it `contenteditable='true'`
2. Click inside the `<p>` at char position 108

   - Prints "rangeCount: 1, type: Caret, anchorOffset: 108" (EXPECTED)
3. Click a different nodes `<p>` at char 5

   - Prints "rangeCount: 1, type: Caret, anchorOffset: 108" (NOT EXPECTED)
   - Destroys redactor and recreates around 2nd node

In steps 1 & 3, the "selection" clearly hasn't been passed to the `<p>`.  I assume this is because at these points, the `<p>` in question doesn't have any `contenteditable='true'` in its ancestry so it can't really have a "selection" per se.

#### My Question:

How can I get the caret position under the mouse cursor within a non-contenteditable'd `<p>` tag when the user clicks one?

Any help/advice much appreciated!

(Unfortunately, Redactor is not freely available so I can't include it in a jsFiddle example)

### UPDATE

These "node" divs are also using jQueryUI's draggable and droppable widgets.  Upon disabling these, the handler outputs the expected values for the selection... interesting.  Unfortunately the drag/drop functionality is a requirement..

Comment: hi Alex, did you solve this issue? I'm struggling ...

Comment: @JuanLanus sorry we never did find a solution.  We ended up abandoning Redactor and using React instead.  It was a brilliant decision that has enabled us to develop a far richer application while at the same time eliminating stupid little problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this'll work, but try adding a small `setTimeout` before getting the selection. This should cause it to give you the selection *after* the click, and in that callback you can then initialise the editor.

Comment: I would also like to suggest that onmouseup may be the correct time to check the window.getSelection()

Comment: No go - delaying 50ms (or 500ms) the selection changes to position '1', as the redactor initialisation puts the caret at the beginning of the new contenteditable `<p>

Comment: No, I mean put the entire contents of the click event in a timeout - as in, `setTimeout(function() {selection = window.getSelection(), document.setRedactor(node);},50)` - something like that, but tidier :p

Comment: I tried both - wrapping the entire handler content (shows `type: None`) and wrapping just the `getSelection` / `console.log` statements (shows `type: Caret`, `anchorOffset: 1`)